# Implement a function which returns a pointer

Tags: pointers, go, syslog

I have implemented the syslog daemon service in my golang app. I used syslog.New in main package and it works but now, I want to export it to another package.

```
package config

import (
    "log/syslog"
)

func LogBook() ? {
    sysLog, _ := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_LOCAL0|syslog.LOG_ERROR, "myapp") // syslog.New returns (*Writer, error)
    return ?
}
```

How can I implement this function?
After, how can I use this variable 'sysLog' in other packages?

Thank you!

Comment: How about a *syslog.Writer ? What's the actual question because that answer is just too obvious.

Comment: If I do this question it's because I'm rookie in golang and the answer is not obvious for me... I don't know how I can write the function.

Comment: If new to Go the best recommendation is to take the Tour of Go twice and read through Effective Go afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple as @Volker said,

```
func LogBook() *syslog.Writer {
    sysLog, _ := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_LOCAL0|syslog.LOG_ERROR, "myapp")
    return sysLog
}
```

Usage Example:

```
func main(){
    w := LogBook()
    w.Info("message")
}
```

Please notice:

- This package is not implemented on Windows. As the syslog package is frozen, Windows users are encouraged to use a package outside of the standard library. For background, see https://golang.org/issue/1108.
- This package is not implemented on Plan 9.
- This package is not implemented on NaCl (Native Client).

Comment: Thank you @Elad. That's exactly what I did at the first time but after, I don't get to take the variable, for example sysLog.Info("message"), in my main function :S

Comment: I edited. In any case, you should listen to @Volker advice and take the GO Tour.

Comment: Yes, he has reason.